# Merge @media rules via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm currently using LESS to 'bubble' my media queries. So my outputted CSS is something like this -

```
header {
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    color: green;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    color: blue;
  }
}

section {
  color: green;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    color: blue;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  section {
     color: red;
  }
}
```

As you can see there's a separate rule declaration for each element (header/section/whatever) for each media query being used.

Can I use jQuery to go through a CSS file and 'collate' all similar @media rules (whatever they are) and have an output (appendto?) bit of html to copy and paste?

EDIT: 
If I created an 'app' could I copy and paste the raw CSS and get jQuery to find/replace/collate the media queries so all the same ones are together?

EDIT:
To hopefully stop any confusion I want to create an app that takes a RAW copy and pasted bit of text (that'll be CSS) which would then compile and merge the correct @media rules together. Which you could then paste back into your code editor. Not actually 'touching' a CSS file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge all similar CSS, and you need to write media query size format in descending order like this

```
header {
 color: red;
}
section {
   color: green;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   header {
    color: blue;
   }
   section {
    color: red;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   section {
    color: blue;
   }
   header {
    color: green;
   }
}
```

For reference check this

http://stackcomplete.com/media-queries-for-adaptive-to-responsive-websites/

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does explain how to build the requested app? Nowadays this can easily be done by using [browersify](http://browserify.org/). This solution also uses [group-css-media-queries](https://github.com/Se7enSky/group-css-media-queries).

1. install browserify: npm install -g browserify
2. npm install group-css-media-queries
3. npm install jquery (main cause this is asked in the question)

Now you can create a `main.js`:

```
var gcmq = require('group-css-media-queries');
var $ = require('jquery');
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#css').submit(function(e){
$('#grouped textarea').val(gcmq($('#css textarea').val()));  
e.preventDefault();    
});
});
```

Then run in your console:

```
>> browserify main.js -o app.js
```

The resulting `app.js` can be included in the HTML file now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

The HTML page for your app should look something like that shown beneath:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Merge Media queries</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
<h1>Unmerged CSS code:</h1>    
<form id="css">
<textarea id="csscode" cols="50" rows="10">header {
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    color: green;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    color: blue;
  }
}

section {
  color: green;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    color: blue;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  section {
     color: red;
  }
}</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="merge @media">
</form><br>
<h1>Merged @media:</h1> 
<form id="grouped">  
<textarea id="groupedcode" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>    
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/bassjobsen/pen/NqrJeM (possible loads slow due to large JS code), also see http://codepen.io/bassjobsen/pen/rVLgod (same without jQuery (see below) and minified JS, should load faster)

Notice if you use jQuery only to handle the form you will create a lot of overhead. Possible use plain JavaScript in your main.js:

```
var gcmq = require('group-css-media-queries');
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("css").onsubmit = function onSubmit(form) {
        var unmerged = document.getElementById('csscode').value;
        document.getElementById('groupedcode').value = gcmq(unmerged);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In stead building your own app you should consider to use a postprocess plugin for your @media merging, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30325426/1596547