# LESSCSS: how to compile using last version and grouping media queries

Tags: compilation, less

I usually develop LESS code using JS compiler in DEV environment, so I compile CSS only when going to PRODUCTION one.

I have 2 needs compiling LESS into CSS:

1. Compile LESS not automatically, but only when I manually want to do it, **but using always last version of compiler released** (often tools like WinLess have not up-to-date versions)
2. Auto-merging media queries (using media queries inside nested rules, results in numerous repetition of the same media query. **Compiler should detect it and group all css declaration inside a unique media query** )

How to do that? (possibly without node.js, I don't have it)

Comment: I'd say tools like `grunt` and `gulp` are the answer for this (not counting the "always last version of compiler" - new version may have critical bugs though you can always schedule a script to update tools every hour for example). There're few (two at least for the `grunt`) "media query grouping" plugins as well. You are also not limited to any paricular IDE as it's usually configured to compile/live-reload on file change (i.e. you can use *any* IDE/editor).

Comment: >possibly without node.js, I don't have it - Then do have it. Looking for specific IDE/editor with built-in Less compiler and all the stuff you mentioned is a waste of time (this century is modular - any "I can do everything" tool is a dead-end in a long run).

Comment: I found few time ago a lessjs tools executed from command line with a command like "lessjs style.less syle.css" (approximately) that runs only when I manually launch the command, but media query grouping did not executed. 
I thought about a tool to which I provide "less.js" interpreter (for example, the specific version that I could download form official site) and that create final css.

Comment: for the command line and media query grouping, run: `npm install less`, `npm install less-plugin-group-css-media-queries` and then `less styles.less styles.css --group-css-media-queries`

Comment: @BassJobsen: I found this kind of commands in many places, but I never find also requirement to execute them. What do I have to install in my PC in order to execute it? In my opinion LESS website take for granted too much things, especially section about "usage"

Comment: you should install node.js, see http://nodejs.org/download/, which includes npm already, to run lessc from the command line

Comment: I wrote "possibly without node.js" :D Anyway.... I read about possibility to use Grunt instead to do the same task. Please, what's the difference between two approaches? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less runs inside 3 environments: Node, browser and inside Rhino. Currently there is no Rhino support for v2, alternatively you can use https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j, see [How do I build the Rhino specific versions of less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810518/how-do-i-build-the-rhino-specific-versions-of-less).

Some PHP ports are available at http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/ and http://leafo.net/lessphp. Both ports seem not to be able to run the latest version of Less. Also @media merging does not work with PHP, see: [Group multiple media queries formed as output of LESS css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237267/group-multiple-media-queries-formed-as-output-of-less-css)

> I wrote "possibly without node.js" :D Anyway.... I read about
>   possibility to use Grunt instead to do the same task. Please, what's
>   the difference between two approaches? thanks

Grunt (and Gulp) are both JavaScript task runners and require Node.js too:

> Grunt and Grunt plugins are installed and managed via npm, the Node.js
>   package manager. Grunt 0.4.x requires stable Node.js versions >=
>   0.8.0.

No, the easiest way to solve your issues is getting Node.js:

1. Install Node.js (which includes npm), see https://nodejs.org/download/
2. Then you in your console (command prompt) `npm install -g less`. Mac users should run the Terminal.app and Windows users can use the `cmd` command.

Now you can compile your less files as follows:

```
>> lessc main.less main.css
```

**Auto-merging media queries:**

Clean-css supports @media merging since v3, and so does the [less-plugin-clean-css](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css). So run in your console:

1. npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css

Now you can compile your less files as follows:

```
>> lessc --clean-css="advanced" main.less
```

less-plugin-clean-css sets the --skip-advanced true by default you should explicit set the `advanced` option for @media merging